# Can I apply for jobs in Canada while still a student?

Tags: immigration, canada, job-hunting

I want to get a job in Canada before I complete my studies. I am currently a student in a country not my own. I am interested in getting work experience after my graduation in September.

I know that I need a job offer, work permit, etc. to emigrate to Canada, but I don't know what should I do first.

Am I able to apply for employment before receiving my degree certification?

Comment: What is a "particular country" and what degree you're getting? Here you have a questionnaire which you can use to determine what you need http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/apply-who-permit.asp

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, yes you can. You can apply for employment before receiving your degree certification however the under that scenario a company would have to hire you, then help you apply for a work permit as a Young Professional or International Co-op (Internship), or you apply for a working holiday permit (if you're between 18-35) etc.

Good luck hunting.